# How to ignore ' character in ansible replace module

Tags: ansible

I want to replace the listen_address='localhost' to listen_address='*' in postgres configuration file using ansible. I am getting stuck due to the ' character.

This is what i tried

```
replace: path=/usr/pgsql-9.6/data/postgresql.conf regexp='listen_addresses=\\'localhost\\' replace=\\'listen_addresses=*\\' remote_src=yes backup=yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me, please try

```
  - name: test
    replace:
     path:  /tmp/test
     regexp: listen_address='localhost'
     replace: listen_address='*'
```

Comment: Sorry but doesnt work

  replace: path=/usr/pgsql-9.6/data/postgresql.conf 
  regexp=#listen_addresses='localhost' replace=listen_addresses='*' 
   remote_src=yes backup=yes